# Boldening parts of string ignoring case python,HTML

Tags: python, search-engine

I want to bold parts of text for my search engine... The major engine is in Python..
I have the search term in a var called q (for query)... for this example lets assume that the search term is "BlOg" I compute the search results and i want to replace all occurences of "BlOg" ignoring the case which should then replace all "blog" and "BLOG" and "BLog" etc. with the same text but wrapped in `<b>` tags...

For example:

```
Search term: "BlOg"<br>
result 1 before: "CS Blog"<br>
after: "CS &lt;b&gt;Blog&lt;b>

result 2 before: "Stacker blog" [notice the "blog" is lowercase]<br> 
after: "Stacker &lt;b&gt;blog&lt;b>
```

Note that I didn't change the case; I just surrounded it with `<b>` tags.

Comment: Are you using Django?

Comment: @Emil nope!
just standard Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
import re
bolded = bolded = re.sub(r"(?i)(%s)" % query, r"<b>\1</b>", content)
```

Sample :

```
>>> import re
>>> content = "fox iN a blog"
>>> query = "in"
>>> bolded = re.sub(r"(?i)(%s)" % query, r"<b>\1</b>", content)
>>> bolded
'fox <b>in</b> a blog'
```

Ability to pass an `IGNORECASE` flag to `sub` was added in 2.7, so I added the `(?i)` in front of the regex pattern to make it case insensitive.

Comment: did not work...
In [5]: title = "CS 253 BLog"

In [6]: bolded = re.sub(r"(%s)" % "BLOG","<b>\1</b>",title,re.IGNORECASE)

In [7]: bolded
Out[7]: 'CS 253 BLog'

In [8]:

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it. Added a `r` before replacement pattern.

Comment: does not work with different cases, if it works with different cases i'll accept your answer @Emil

Comment: Ok, got it to work, for some reason the `IGNORECASE` flag was being ignored.